How to add an underline to a selected tabItem in WPF TabControl
Problem
I'm working on a WPF project and need assistance with styling a TabControl.
The header of my main window features a label on the left and a TabControl on the right, containing three TabItems with icon-only content.
Objective: How can I add an underline to the selected TabItem in a TabControl that moves when different TabItems are selected? the underline should be placed in the bottom border of the TabControl
Code
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Wpf.Views.Header"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding HeaderView, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Border CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" BorderBrush="#262260" BorderThickness="5" Background="#262260">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent" Height="32" Margin="16,0,0,0" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Images/White.png" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <TabControl Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10">
                <TabItem IsSelected="True">
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Button Command="{Binding ShowPageA}">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="Images/PageA.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>    
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem>
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Button Command="{Binding ShowPageB}">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/Images/PageB.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem>
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Button Command="{Binding ShowPageC}">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="/Images/PageC.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </TabItem.Header>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>


Any examples or guidance on how to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated.

You can always override the default template to add elements.
Another solution that does not require to reimplement the visual state behavior is to make proper use of templating.
In general, you should employ templates and styles to eliminate repetitive code. In your case this repetitive code is the content of the TabItem headers.
Using a RadioButton (instead of a Button) also improves the handling of the TabItem selection. A RadioButton perfectly reflects the mutual exclusive selection state of the TabItem.
The following example shows how to add a red horizontal line, using a Border, by defining a DataTemplate for the TabItem.HeaderTemplate property and a Style that implicitly applies this template to all TabItem elements of the TabControl.
The example also shows how to eliminate the repetitive code by moving the inline ControlTemplate to a resource dictionary. This also improves the configuration of the buttons and therefore the readability of your code.
<TabControl Grid.Column="2"
            Background="Transparent"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="10">
  <TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
      <StackPanel>

        <!-- The host for the header content -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />

        <!-- Use a Border as it will naturally stretch to fill the available space dynamically -->
        <Border x:Name="SelectionMarker"
                Background="Red"
                Height="2"
                Visibility="Hidden" />
      </StackPanel>

      <DataTemplate.Triggers>

        <!-- Only show the selection marker when the item is selected -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=IsSelected}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="SelectionMarker"
                  Property="Visibility"
                  Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Apply the DataTemplate to all TabItems -->
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" />
    </Style>

    <!-- The exatracted ControlTemplate of each button (now a RadioButton) -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate"
                     TargetType="RadioButton">

      <!-- Set image source via the Content property of the button -->
      <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"
             Width="24"
             Height="24" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Apply the ControlTemplate to all RadioButtons within the TabControl -->
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
      <Setter Property="Template"
              Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />
      <Setter Property="IsChecked"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=IsSelected}" />
      <Setter Property="GroupName"
              Value="TabHeaderSelector" />
    </Style>
  </TabControl.Resources>

  <TabItem IsSelected="True">
    <TabItem.Header>
      <RadioButton Command="{Binding ShowPageA}"
                   Content="Images/PageA.png" />
    </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
      <RadioButton Command="{Binding ShowPageB}"
                   Content="Images/PageB.png" />
    </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
      <RadioButton Command="{Binding ShowPageC}"
                   Content="Images/PageC.png" />
    </TabItem.Header>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>


thanks for your detailed response, now I can see the underline in the tabItem,
but what I actually want is that the underline will be placed in the main grid border, as I pointed in the screenshot

Your image shows three tab items where one is underlined. Please be more specific.

＠Simon You haven't shown the enough code to exactly reproduce your visual design. Why can you expect the others provide the code which match your design?
